# As of 2018 October, what has EOS ram prices been?

Tags: ram, price

It's 2018 october, what has the ram prices been like? Is there a chart to show the historic prices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [FeeXplorer](https://eos.feexplorer.io/); attached below is a linear chart from June until today for EOS/Kb using 60 minutes candles. However, restricting the time horizon to exclude unusual behaviour may provide a better visualisation of current trends.

[image: historic RAM prices]

Comment: Why was there the initial spike in july? And what made it pave off?

Comment: it was shortly after launch when many were buying ram for speculation or for saving for dapps, and the supply of RAM was not increasing. to fix this, the community decided to increase the RAM supply by 1KB every block, and eventually the volatility decreased